# Stop UITabBarController to rotate but UIViewController to Rotate

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible somehow to stop UITabBarController to rotate but the UIViewControllers (which are items of UITabBarController) to rotate.

So when the device is portrait mode, the tab bar will be at bottom of screen but if the user rotates the device to left side, the tabbarcontroller must remain on left side (should not come at bottom) but only the UIViewController gets rotated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would Listen to the UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification notifications,
and rotate the View by myself (new frame and rotation transform).

Comment: UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;

    if(interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        NSLog(@"True");
        self.view.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), 0.0);
        // Rotate 90 degrees to hide it off screen
        CGAffineTransform rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotationTransform, DegreeToRadian(90));
        self.view.transform = rotationTransform;

    }

Comment: I tried using above code but not working correctly. I also thought about rotating view itself but was not sure which is more efficient way (animation will use battery more)